# checking to see if checkbox is checked rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, twilio

I am trying to create my first rails app from scratch but I don't think I should have used rails for this after all. I have a button that uses a method make_calls and within make calls I have it making a bunch of different calls seperated by sleep statements, however I need these to only execute if the calls_check checkbox is checked. Here is what I have:
In my Controller:

```
# called from inside make_calls method
def individual_call(to_phone, xml_url)

call = @client.calls.create(
                           url: xml_url,
                           to: to_phone,
                           from: '+13474275841',
                           timeout: 20
                         )
if params[:calls_check] == '1'
    puts call.sid
end
```

In my View:

```
<body>
    <div class="buttonDiv w3-display-middle">
         <%= check_box :calls_check, id: "calls_check" %>Make Calls
         <%= button_to "Start Call Sequence", action: "make_calls" %>
    </div>
</body>
```

But even when the checkbox is unchecked it is still making the calls. Any advice?

Comment: Check your `params[:calls_check]` if you are getting the correct value that you are comparing with 1.

Comment: Show the server log for request 1. with checkbox checked 2. with checkbox unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [check_box_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag) Instead of [check_box](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box)

Reason being `check_box` accepts 2nd parameters as a method (*It’s intended that method returns an integer and if that integer is above zero, then the checkbox is checked*)

Using `check_box_tag`

```
<%= check_box_tag :calls_check, 1, false %>
```

Which means that once checkbox will be checked it will send parameter as `'1'` and by default it will be `unchecked`, In case of unchecked it won't send parameter of `calls_check`(i.e `params[:calls_check] = nil`)

At controller side

```
# called from inside make_calls method
def individual_call(to_phone, xml_url)

call = @client.calls.create(
                           url: xml_url,
                           to: to_phone,
                           from: '+13474275841',
                           timeout: 20
                         ) if params[:calls_check].eql?('1')
    puts call.sid
end
```

Wrap check_box with form so that it send data on button click,

replace `make_calls_path` with the make_call action path and also its `method` `get` or `post`. according to your defined routes

```
<body>
  <div class="buttonDiv w3-display-middle">
    <%=form_tag make_calls_path, method: :get do %>
      <%= check_box_tag :calls_check, id: "calls_check" %>Make Calls
      <%= submit_tag "Start Call Sequence"%>
    <%end%>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `params[:calls_check].present? && params[:calls_check].eql?('1')` is same as `params[:calls_check].eql?('1')`

Comment: Thanks for the help! When I am running it `if params[:calls_check].eql?('1')` keeps returning false no matter what so it never makes the calls... any idea?

Comment: Can you show the Params log by using debugger ? Make sure you are using `check_box_tag`? Not `check_box`

Comment: @DylanPatch Ohh i got it, you have to bind `check_box_tag` with `button`  i.e wrap it in form , check the update answer.

Comment: Sorry i'm still really struggling with Ruby, the make_calls_path doesn't exist. What do I have to do to fix that?

Comment: Oh wait @Gabbar I just had to make it landing_make_calls_path. But I am still not able to get it to get the params for the checkbox

Comment: `[4] pry(#<LandingController>)> params[:calls_check].eql?('1')
=> false
[5] pry(#<LandingController>)> params[:calls_check]
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"{:id=>\"calls_check\"}"=>"1"} permitted: false>`

Comment: Well it seems you didn't use the code I have provided.seem you are still using `check_box` and I have mentioned `check_box_tag`. Please use the latest code and let me know for any further guidance.

Comment: Sorry I had tried the `check_box_tag` unsuccessfully, when I have that my pry shows even less... `[3] pry(#<LandingController>)> params[:calls_check]
=> "{:id=>\"calls_check\"}"
[4] pry(#<LandingController>)> params[:calls_check].eql?('1')
=> false` @Gabbar

Comment: @DylanPatch Could you try latest update code also don't forget to use `chekbox_tag` inside a `form_tag` as suggested in answer.?

Comment: That is with the updated code :( I am having no luck on this at all. @Gabbar

Comment: @DylanPatch Actually i have tried this code myself, before write the answer, i believe you are still using check_box not check_box_tag cause check_box sends param as like your  `params[:calls_check] => "{:id=>\"calls_check\"}"` .